# How to convert char[] to ByteBuffer in JNI?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, bytebuffer

I want to pass a ByteBuffer over JNI to C++, as the buffer to receive an image decoded from AVDecode, though the buffer is correctly filled in C++, but the ByteBuffer at the Java side is still empty.
Please help me to find out where is the error. Thanks.
pOutBuffer is the ByteBuffer passed via JNI.

```
jclass ByteBufferClass = env->GetObjectClass(pOutBuffer);  
jmethodID ArraryMethodId = env->GetMethodID(ByteBufferClass,"array","()[B");  
jmethodID ClearMethodId = env->GetMethodID(ByteBufferClass,"clear","()Ljava/nio/Buffer;");  

//clear buffer  
env->CallObjectMethod(pOutBuffer,ClearMethodId);  

jbyteArray OutByteArrary = (jbyteArray)env->CallObjectMethod(pOutBuffer,ArraryMethodId);  
jbyte OutJbyte = env->GetByteArrayElements(OutByteArrary,0);  

Out = (unsigned char*)OutJbyte;
DecodeSize = AVDecode(m_pVideoDecode, (unsigned char *)In, inputSize, (unsigned char **)&Out, (int *)&pBFrameKey);
```

The decoding is correct and I can see that 'Out' is filled with the output image, however, when this function returns, the pOutBuffer at the Java side is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

How was the ByteBuffer created? Is it a [direct or non-direct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#direct) ByteBuffer?

If it's a direct ByteBuffer which has been created in Java using the `allocateDirect` method you can us `GetDirectBufferAddress` in your native code to get the direct address of the ByteBuffer and any changes there should be reflected in Java.

Comment: I tried with allocateDirect() and using the method of GetDirectBufferAddress(), but it's still empty, now I want to know if it's a ByteBuffer which has been created in Java using the allocate, I should be using which method? thanks.